# Upgrade danish Windows XP Home 32 bit to Windows 7 or 8 Pro 64 bit English

Tags: windows, upgrade, license

.. or am I really asking too much of the upgrading license, and should just buy a new full Windows 7 /8 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now Microsoft is running a sale on Windows 8 *Pro* upgrades from most any previous version for $39.99 (US market). Note, however, that if you run the upgrade analyzer and then the download from this XP system, it will only download the 32-bit version of Windows 8.

You can, and it's been documented as working, make the purchase but then download the file from a Windows 7 64-bit system. The installer will be a 64-bit Windows 8 installer, but it will be a clean install. So you'll need to reinstall all apps.

Make sure you back up your files somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

[You need to do a clean installation to upgrade from Windows XP to Windows 7](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/help/upgrading-from-windows-xp-to-windows-7), but according to [this thread](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_install/windows-xp-to-windows-7-upgrade-license/ac467df7-a642-4c2d-9e03-a3001885044e)

> Any Windows 7 Upgrade license can be used to install Windows 7 on a computer that is currently running Windows XP.

Although i must admit I don't see that in the tutorial